# Web Resource was not found

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, webresource.axd

I've spent the last day trying to get a checkbox validator to work. I found some starting code on the 4GuysFromRolla website, however this was coded back in 2006 and doesn't play alongside updatepanels.

I've made changes and now it works. As I'd made quite a few changes I wanted to standardise it and use it alongside other utility classes, so I created a new class project and copied the code verbatim.

The problem is that the original works, but I get a WebResource not found error on my new class project.

The differences are: The original was a web application project:

- my new project is simply a class library project.
- The original assembly and namespace have changed.

Both contain a single class and a resource file (.js)
Both resource files are contained in the root directory
Both resource files are set to embed resource

I'm running out of ideas, and have exhausted the answers I've found on the web with no success.

Is there an issue with the fact that its a class library?  Have I perhaps overlooked something else?

Its pretty difficult to see beyond those 2 questions because the project is so small and insignificant.

Here's the code that does work:

```
    if (this.RenderUplevel && this.Page != null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Page, this.GetType(), "skmValidators.skmValidators.js");
    }
```

Here's the code that doesn't:

```
    if (this.RenderUplevel && Page != null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Page, this.GetType(), "ValidationExtender.EvaluationFunctions.js");
    }
```

Anyone give any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error turned out to be a mismatch between the dll's in the test page.